# What is the `data-target` attribute in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you tell me what is the system or behavior behind the `data-target` attribute used by Bootstrap 3?

I know that data-toggle used to aim API JavaScript of Bootstrap of graphical functionality.

Answer (score 140):

`data-target` is used by bootstrap to make your life easier. You (mostly) do not need to write a single line of Javascript to use their pre-made [JavaScript components](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript).

The `data-target` attribute should contain a CSS selector that points to the HTML Element that will be changed.

[Modal Example Code from BS3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples):

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  [...]
</div>
```

In this example, the button has `data-target="#myModal"`, if you click on it, `<div id="myModal">...</div>` will be modified (in this case faded in).
This happens because `#myModal` in CSS selectors points to elements that have an `id` attribute with the `myModal` value.

Further information about the HTML5 "data-" attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: this is like a selector CSS engine and nothing other ?

Comment: @miltone - exactly, not like. `data-target` accepts a CSS selector that points to the relevant element.

Comment: just to be sure , class="modal fade" , The fade keyword makes the element fade <div id="myModal">  The modal keyword makes the <div id="myModal"> hidden until it is shown ( for this example , when the button is clicked ) ?

Answer (score 28):

The toggle tells Bootstrap what to do and the target tells Bootstrap which element is going to open. So whenever a link like that is clicked, a modal with an id of “basicModal” will appear.