# Bootstrap - How to realize an modal popup with JSP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, popup, modal-dialog

I'm trying to realize an modal popup with JSP, using Spring MVC.

In my *index.jsp* I have this href link:

```
<a href="findCompany" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#findCompany">Find company</a>
```

and, **always in this .jsp**, there is this code fragment:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="findCompany" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on *find company* href link, my @Controller redirects me in findCompany.jsp, where there is the form for find a company.

Here's the code of this .jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Azienda</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4><p>Cerca un'azienda <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span></p></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" action="returnCompany">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeAzienda" placeholder="Inserisci il nome" required>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cerca</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

findCompany.jsp is shown like an modal popup, and that's is what I want.

**Ok, everything works.**

But, if I remove, from index.jsp, this one:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="findCompany" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

nothing works.

Why? I'm wrong something with the modal class.

I wish that this last code there wasn't.
Just link in index.jsp and modal form in findCompany.jsp. It's possible?
How to?

Sorry for bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note the `data-target="#findCompany"` in your link.  `#findCompany` refers to an HTML element with `id="findCompany"`.

If you delete that element from your page (i.e. by deleting)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="findCompany" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link will no longer have an element corresponding to its `data-target` and it won't seem to work.

For info on what `data-target`s are and how to use them - you might like to look at this question [what-is-the-data-target-in-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944735/what-is-the-data-target-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Ok, I understand.

So, I can't do anything? If I put id="findCompany" in principal div of findCompany.jsp, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve different to what is happening now.  Is there a reason you want to remove that element from index.jsp?

Comment: The reason is that I don't like how I implemented it. It's ugly to see, I think.

I just want to have a link in index.jsp which refers to modal-content  in findCompany.jsp.

Comment: OK - you're just wondering about whether there is a "cleaner" way or something?  I think I'm not the best person to answer in that case - I've only used bootstrap a little, I can debug, but I'm not an expert in all the ways you can use it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `<%@include file="findCompany.jsp"%>`.