# How to have bootstrap dropdown in angular?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown with checkboxes. I want to use this in Angular.

http://codepen.io/bseth99/pen/fboKH (i dont use any of the javascript in there and I wrap the dropdown in a form)

```
<form>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="HomepageController">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="button-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="callMe()" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="callMe()" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="callMe()" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Inside HomepageController:

```
$scope.callMe = function (event){
 event.preventDefault();
return false;
}
```

I notice that whenever I click on an option or anywhere in the checkbox, it redirects and refreshes the page to go to /#. I tried putting an ng-click on the "a" tag such that it calls a function in a controller that has "return false", no luck. Page still redirects. How do I prevent the page from redirecting and output the "option" that is checked?

The issue is......

1. I want the checking of a box to trigger an event.
2. Checkboxes don't appear to actually check when I click on the checkbox.
3. Want to make sure I can check multiple boxes without the dropdown closing itself after clicking on any individual option.

Comment: Use `angular-ui-bootstrap` instead of standard bootstrap with jquery. See [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931315/how-to-preventdefault-on-anchor-tags. If that's not working, something else is awry.

Comment: I suppose the right question to ask is why you have anchors around inputs. That just seems wrong.

Comment: I have anchors because I want an ng-click event to detect when a box is checked so I can maintain a list of "checked" checkboxes. If there is another way to do it..

Comment: Ng-change on the checkbox instead?

Comment: try data-target instade of href [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944735/what-is-the-data-target-attribute-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ....>
```

it's essentially a no-op and will cause no navigation.