# How to make dropdown expand clicking on the button element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

Currently the dropdown menu appears only if I click on the img tag. How to make it appear when I click on the button tag? Here is my code:

```
<div class="btn btn-link dropdown account-menu-btn">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle icon-el" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="~/Assets/profile_pic.jpg" class="img-circle">
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Create
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I modified the code using data-target, but I still need to click on the image and not on the button to expand the dropdown menu. Any sugestions?

```
<div class="btn btn-link dropdown account-menu-btn" style="background-color:yellow" data-target="#myModal">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle icon-el" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="~/Assets/profile_pic.jpg" class="img-circle">
                </a>
                <ul id="myModal" class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href='@Url.Action("About", "Home")'>
                            Create
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: That HTML is not great. You shouldn't have an anchor etc inside a button tag. Instead of a button the container should probably just be a DIV. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: So with div is a best practice? I redid it. But now how to open the menu clicking on the 'div' and not only on the img?

Comment: You can add a `data-target` attribute to your anchor tag, and then add an id to the element that you want to expand whenever the button is clicked. `data-target="#elementToExpand"`

Comment: @Healforgreen what will this do?

Comment: @v.g. The short answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944735/what-is-the-data-target-attribute-in-bootstrap-3) explains it well.  That attribute may be restricted to button elements, but I am not sure.  It's been awhile since I've used Bootstrap.

Comment: I added data-target but It doesn't work. I still need to click on the image itself and not the yellow button. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is clearly stated in the [twitter-bootstrap javascript section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

Your code isn't really too far from what's on there:

```
<div class="btn btn-link dropdown account-menu-btn">
    <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="~/Assets/profile_pic.jpg" class="img-circle">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Create</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No, this doesn't help. I still get the "hand" mouse pointer on the div but I can expand the menu clicking only on the image

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to do it with Javascript and Jquery.

```
$( '#BUTTONID' ).click(function() { 
    $( '#MENUID' ).toggle();
});
```

This is a very condensed version, but it is ought to work.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do best practices, not hacks :)

Comment: Basically it is a good practice for Javascript. I don't know if you're interested in learning it. If you are you should check out the module 'make an interactive website' on codecademy.com (it's free ;) )